# MacOS 12 Ukelele Default Keyboard

Tags: monterey, input-source, ukelele

I have made a keyboard using Ukelele that fits my needs perfectly. However, the system requires me to have another, default, Latin keyboard. That is to say, it will not recognise my Ukelele keyboard as a default keyboard. Is there any way I can basically integrate my Ukelele layout into the OS like any other Latin keyboard so that I can have a single Latin input method?

※ I have tried doing other methods I found online for much older version of OSX, but they have not worked unfortunately.

Comment: Try asking in the group for Ukelele.   https://groups.google.com/g/ukelele-users?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

I have my Ukelele keyboard installed since 2011 and updated Ukelele yesterday (I have macOS Monterey on MBP M1).
I have it installed *beside* the pre-installed keyboard layouts like US English. Now I can choose one of these when I click on the keyboard layouts in the menu bar top right. The one last chosen will be kept until you choose another, regardless whether you reboot.

Comment: I also have my layout along side another, similar, but less useful layout. I'd like to reduce it to one layout though rather than having it function beside a redundant keyboard